# How to retrieve the proper Subnet Resource Id to create a virtual network rule?

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I created a virtual network like so:

```
$virtualNetwork = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name MyVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName TestResourceGroup -Location centralus -AddressPrefix "10.0.0.0/16"
```

Then I created a subnet for it and then set the virtual network:

```
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name backendSubnet -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -AddressPrefix "10.0.2.0/24"
$virtualNetwork | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
```

I then get my newly-created subnet and give it an Id:

```
$subnet = $virtualNetwork | Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name backendSubnet
$subnet.Id = "resourceId"
```

And try to add this to my AzureRmDataLakeStore, but it fails:

```
Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule -Account MyAccount -Name VNRule -SubnetId $subnet.Id
Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule: Subnet resource ID 'resourceId' is invalid.
```

Does anyone know what I should be entering for the -SubnetId flag? Thank you.

Solution from start to finish (thank you @AdminOfThings):

```
$virtualNetwork = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name MyVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName TestResourceGroup -Location centralus -AddressPrefix "10.0.0.0/16"
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name backendSubnet -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -AddressPrefix "10.0.2.0/24"
$virtualNetwork = $virtualNetwork | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule -Account MyAccount -Name VNRule -SubnetId $subnet.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `$virtualNetwork` and `$subnet` will contain the subnetID short name. The subnetID syntax you are attempting to enter is the `Name` property of the `PSSubnet` object.

```
Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule -Account MyAccount -Name VNRule -SubnetId $subnet.Name
```

It appears you want to give `$subnet` a new ID and then pass that into `Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule`. When you update `$subnet.Id`, you are only updating a variable and not the backend Azure object. I don't know that it is even possible to update that object's property and have it reflect in Azure without recreating it.

When you update the properties in `$virtualNetwork` and execute `Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork`, you will need to store that command output into `$virtualNetwork` again. Only then will `$virtualNetwork` contain the updated object as it exists in Azure.

Comment: It then states: `"Add-AzureRmDataLakeStoreVirtualNetworkRule: Subnet resource ID 'backendSubnet' is invalid`

Comment: This is because you are not querying for your object after making changes. When you run `Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork`, you need to do another `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork` to see your changes.